# How to identify PID or user of large mapped file in Windows - task manager / Resource Monitor are insufficient

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2012-r2

In Windows, in this particular case Windows Server 2012, normally if something is using a lot of RAM you can use the Task Manager or Resource Monitor to find the PID / user and kill it or ask them to kill it.

Some programs, like SAS, use mapped files for some particular database-like joins/operations that have the potential to grow exponentially in size, such as when a "bad join" occurs (unexpectedly creating exponential duplicates).

Using some MS TechNet tools like RAMMap I can see the files that are eating up all the server's memory and threatening to cause a crash/freeze. I have no way to identify the process or user associated with that file, however.

How can I find the related PID or user?

Comment: It turned out that the files were created by SAS but SAS doesn't properly report its file or memory usage to Windows when a bad join occurs

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Computer Management\Shared folders\Open files.

Is that what you are looking for?

https://serverfault.com/questions/702716/how-to-close-shared-files-on-server-2012

Comment: This is super-interesting! +1 Give me a couple of hours to validate this solution and I'll mark it as the answer if it works :)

Comment: OK I'm in that screen and I see some stuff. Currently SAS isn't overburdening the server, but I see 1 entire drive listed with my coworker's username and then another particular file is listed under him on a different drive. I don't think this is the same as those temporary mapped files in SAS that eat up all the RAM? Is there a way to see RAM allocation so that I can be sure? I'll try to answer that for myself as well later this afternoon. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I think this answer is about networked filesharing, like SMB/CIFS stuff. That’s different than `mmap()`ped files.